# Calling method from javascript popup

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
<div class="viewAllEmailModal" style="display: none; position: fixed; _position: absolute; top: 20%; _top:expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop)+20); left: 20%; bottom: 18%; width: 60%; min-width: 500px; padding: 2em; z-index: 9998; background: white; border-radius: .5em; overflow: auto;" >
<apex:form id="ViewAllEmailsForm">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn" onclick="window.reload(); return false;Model.nullifyEmailVariables"/>
```

This piece of code is within a modal window. What I want is that once Cancel button is pressed both the `nullifyEmailVariables` method of class and `window.reload()` would be called.

My current code is not working. The parent page is getting refreshed, but nullifyEmailVariables is not called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please paste your code?

Comment: first call the `nullifyEmailVariables ` then do the `window.reload()`